# Select only rows from sql table that have more than one different values for a second_id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a big Oracle SQL table and I need to select only those rows that have more than one different values for the second_id

Current state:

| first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 | 846 |
| 1004 | 846 |
| 1004 | 849 |
| 1005 | 324 |
| 1005 | 324 |

Expected result:

| first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 | 846 |
| 1004 | 846 |
| 1004 | 849 |

As you can see, all entries with the first_id = 1005 were removed, as they all have the same second_id. As long as there are more than one different values for the second_id, it should keep the rows. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Something's wrong. **More than two** different values means ">". FIRST_ID = 1004 has **two** different values (846 and 849), which means that - with that sample data - you wouldn't get ANYTHING AT ALL as a result. So, either sample data is wrong, or your explanation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) are good for this:

```
create table foo (first_id number, second_id number);

insert into foo values (1004,   846);
insert into foo values (1004,   846);
insert into foo values (1004,   849);
insert into foo values (1005,   324);
insert into foo values (1005,   324);
    
select first_id,second_id
from (
  select first_id,second_id, 
    count(distinct second_id) over (partition by first_id) cnt_distinct
  from foo)
where cnt_distinct > 1;
```

You can run the inner select to see what it returns for each row.